# How to used circular progress when something is loading in c# and other window remains disabled

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, bunifu

Hello everyone I want to create a application which has progress bar ,is loading and other window are disabled in c#

Comment: Hello, what do you use for front end? WPF? Bunifu? There's nothing already built in for that?

Comment: Windows form and bunifu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a progress bar with bunify like you already use it and during the progress bar is showed in a shild window, you deactived other window.

You can make something like that in winform for blocking the parent window:

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.Owner = this;
child.Show();

In ChildForm_Load:
private void ChildForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Owner.Enabled = false;
}

private void ChildForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Owner.Enabled = true;
}
```

and for the progress bar, you can look there: https://bunifuframework.com/products/bunifu-ui-winforms/controls/bunifu-progress-bar/